# just curious if object class are usable in css

Tags: javascript, css, function, object

the java scipts ias a follows :

```
function Person(name,age) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
}
```

in the above object creation function, the class is Person, so can i use ".Person" within my CSS to refer it to all Person class ?

or will I still have to declare the class name in the HTML doc ?

new to coding. was just curious when i was practicing online.

Comment: The class itself is not visible for the user hence don't need any CSS, its output could, most likely using a html element, and that element need a class, which can be dynamically created, and when, you could use an inner function in the given object which will add its name to that output as a class attribute/value

Answer (score 4):

No. CSS is for [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)s provided by DOM, not for JS objects.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have it in the DOM, either by declaring it as a class in the HTML element or injecting it via javascript.